# $\int \frac{a^2}{(a^2-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How can I solve the following integral?

$$\int \frac{a^2}{(a^2-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx$$

Comment: I assume that you just forgot $dx$. Change variable $x=a\sin\theta$ (or $\cos$)

Answer (score 0):

Let, $x=a\sin\theta\Rightarrow \frac{dx}{d\theta}=a\cos\theta\Rightarrow dx=(a\cos\theta)\,d\theta.$

$$\int \frac{a^2a\cos\theta}{(a^2-a^2\sin^2\theta)^\frac{3}{2}}d\theta$$

Thus, by solving this integral we get $\int(\sec^2\theta)\, d\theta = \tan\theta + C$

Since,$$x=a\sin\theta\Rightarrow \sin\theta = \frac{x}{a} \Rightarrow \cos\theta = \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}$$

Since, $\tan\theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$

So, the final result is:

$$\int \sec^2\theta \,d\theta = \tan\theta + C = \frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} + C$$

Note: $C$ is the integration constant.